# checkbox doesn't check for the first row

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, twig

Hello I have 11 rows with 3 checkboxes and 1 checkbox for each row that checks all or unchecks all rows checkboxes. I also have a general checkbox that checks/uncheck all checkboxes of all rows. I have a problem with the first row checkbox, which doesnt check, it checks for the first time all 3 checkboxes but doesnt get checked and after that doesnt change nothing. All other checkboxes work fine. Another thing that happen is that if the general checkbox is checked then the first checkbox of the first row works when check/uncheck but when checkboxes of other rows are checke/unchecked changes are reflected evven for this first checkbox it is checked/unchecked:

```
                                                                            id="selectall">
            {% for group, privs in privileges %}
                <div class="well well-sm priv-panel"><span class="has-success">{{ group }}</span>
                    {% for p in privs %}
                        <span class="priv {% if p.ACTIVE %}priv-active{% else %}priv-inactive{% endif %}">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1 checkbox1_{{ group }}"
                               name="privs[{{ p.PRIVILEGE_ID }}]" id="{{ p.PRIVILEGE_NAME }}"
                               {% if p.ACTIVE %}checked{% endif %}/>
                        <label for="{{ p.PRIVILEGE_NAME }}">{{ p.PRIVILEGE_FRIENDLY_NAME }}</label></span>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input style="float:right;" type="checkbox" class="priv_group_toggle_cb"
                           value="{{ group }}">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

$("#selectall, .priv_group_toggle_cb").on('change', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var checked = $this.is(':checked');
                var cb = null;

                if ($this.hasClass('priv_group_toggle_cb')) {
                    cb = $("[name*=privs]", $this.parent());
                } else {
                    cb = $("[name*=privs], .priv_group_toggle_cb");
                }

                cb.each(function (idx, val) {
                    if (val.checked !== checked) {
                        val.checked = checked;
                        $(val).trigger('change');
                    }
                });
            });

            $(".table-cb-toggle tr").on('click', function () {
                $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").click();
            });

            $(".priv-panel input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
                var parent = $(this).parent().toggleClass('priv-active priv-inactive');
                var div = parent.parent();

                var cb = div.find("input[type=checkbox]:not(.priv_group_toggle_cb)");

                var count = cb.length;
                var checked_cnt = Array.prototype.slice.call(cb).reduce(function (c, i) {
                    return c + (i.checked + 0)
                }, 0);

                div.find(".priv_group_toggle_cb")[0].checked = checked_cnt == count;
            });

            $(".mytable tr td input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
                $(this).next("i").toggleClass('fa fa-check-square-o fa fa-square-o');
            });
```

Comment: Please count how many times "check" is in your first paragraph.

Comment: i didnt get it. could you please be more clear?